# Javascript to Coffeescript conversion doesn't work

Tags: coffeescript

I have the following function that works perfectly in Javascript

```
function graphite_get_data(target) {
return context.metric(function(start, stop, step, callback) {

var fetch_time = new Date().getTime();
if ((fetch_time-current_time) < 6000 && saved_data.length > 0) {
  callback(null, graphite_parse(saved_data)); 
}
else {
// -------------- Begin Request New Data ------------------
  d3.json(host + "/render?format=json"
      + "&target=" + encodeURIComponent(target)
      + "&from=" + graphite_format_date(start - 2 * step)
      + "&until=" + graphite_format_date(stop - 1000), 
      function(data) {
        if (!data) return callback(new Error("unable to load data"));

        current_time = fetch_time    
        saved_data = data;

        callback(null, graphite_parse(data)); 
      });
// -------------- End Request New Data --------------------
} // else
}); // return
}
```

When I try to convert this to coffeescript using http://js2coffee.org, it doesn't work and I'm not sure how to debug:

```
    graphite_get_data = (target) ->
  console.log(global_pod)
  console.log("hi") #prints
    context.metric (start, stop, step, callback) ->
    console.log("hi") #doesn't print
    fetch_time = new Date().getTime()
    if (fetch_time - current_time) < 6000 and saved_data.length > 0
      callback null, graphite_parse(saved_data) # will use global variable test_pod
    else
      # -------------- Begin Request New Data ------------------
      d3.json host + "/render?format=json" + "&target=" + encodeURIComponent(target) + "&from=" + graphite_format_date(start - 2 * step) + "&until=" + graphite_format_date(stop - 1000), (data) ->
        return callback(new Error("unable to load data"))  unless data
        current_time = fetch_time
        saved_data = data
        callback null, graphite_parse(data) #will use global variable test_pod
      # -------------- End Request New Data --------------------
```

Can you advise me on how to debug coffee script?

EDIT: I checked the the javascript generated and saw this

```
 graphite_get_data = function(target) {
  var fetch_time;
  console.log("hi");
  context.metric(function(start, stop, step, callback) {});
  fetch_time = new Date().getTime();

  console.log("hi");

  if ((fetch_time - current_time) < 6000 && saved_data.length > 0) {
          callback(null, graphite_parse(saved_data));
          return true;
  } 

  else {
          d3.json(host + "/render?format=json" + "&target=" + encodeURIComponent(target) + "&from=" + graphite_format_date(start - 2 * step) + "&until=" + graphite_format_date(stop - 1000), function(data) {
            if (!data) {
              return callback(new Error("unable to load data"));
            } // end if

            current_time = fetch_time;
            saved_data = data;
            callback(null, graphite_parse(data));
            return true;
          }); //end function(data)

          return true;
        } //end else 
        // missing });
      };

      graphite_format_date = function(time) {
        return Math.floor(time / 1000);
      };

      return graphite_parse = function(data) {
        var pod_data, pod_json_data;

        pod_json_data = $.grep(data, function(e) { return e.target === test_pod; });
        pod_data = pod_json_data[0]["datapoints"].slice(1).map(function(d) { return d[0]; });
        return pod_data;
      };
    }
  }); // what is this here?? it should be in missing

}).call(this);
```

and found the problem to be }); missing in one place and added in another wrong place

still working on how to fix it

Comment: Why don't you just leave it as JavaScript? Converting JavaScript to CoffeeScript with a tool and then converting the CoffeeScript back to JavaScript with another tool seems bizarre to me. js2coffee seems to be rather buggy, you'd be better off learning CoffeeScript and converting your code with your brain (or just leave it as JavaScript).

Comment: yes you're right, I just thought I should follow the standard where everything is coffeescript under assets

Comment: Just because the Rails guys think something is a good idea doesn't mean that it is a good idea or that you have to follow along. *Opinionated* doesn't mean *right* and the Rails guys are just opinionated and sometimes right.

Comment: yeah thanks! I will give this 30 more minutes if it didn't work I'll keep it as JS ... thanks!

Comment: Okay I'm using JS now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can you advise me on how to debug coffee script?

Sure: use [sourcemaps in Chrome](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/javascript-debugging#source-maps). Keep in mind that sometimes a step in Coffee is several steps in JS, so sometimes you'll see odd looking stepping behavior.

Regarding the conversion of your code, I think you may have copied or pasted something wrong, because it looks fine to me:

```
graphite_get_data = (target) ->
  context.metric (start, stop, step, callback) ->
    fetch_time = new Date().getTime()
    if (fetch_time - current_time) < 6000 and saved_data.length > 0
      callback null, graphite_parse(saved_data)
    else

      # -------------- Begin Request New Data ------------------
      d3.json host + "/render?format=json" + "&target=" + encodeURIComponent(target) + "&from=" + graphite_format_date(start - 2 * step) + "&until=" + graphite_format_date(stop - 1000), (data) ->
        return callback(new Error("unable to load data"))  unless data
        current_time = fetch_time
        saved_data = data
        callback null, graphite_parse(data)
```

I've found js2coffee to be pretty reliable.

The biggest problem with your code is here:

```
context.metric(function(start, stop, step, callback) {});
```

That line didn't come over right in your version, but was fine in my version. I'm not sure why, I suspect you're missing some indents in the coffee code. **Indents in coffeescript are very important.**

I'd also recommend trying [CoffeeScript Enhanced](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/try-coffeescript-enhanced/fldhkfldchaibgaheaogapecjmnkaepe?hl=en) in Chrome -- js2coffee is paying for that traffic and not getting anything for it.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is an indentation problem at the start of the coffeescript.

This is what generates your 2nd javascript:

```
graphite_get_data = (target) ->
  context.metric (start, stop, step, callback) ->
  fetch_time = new Date().getTime()
```

My coffeescript starts:

```
graphite_get_data = (target) ->
  context.metric( (start, stop, step, callback) ->
    fetch_time = new Date().getTime()
    if ...
    else ...
  )
```

Answer (score -1):

> Can you advise me on how to debug coffee script?

You can't. Debug the resulting JavaScript. CoffeeScript isn't run directly, it gets trans-compiled to JavaScript.

Comment: ahh I hate coffeescript! Not sure why rails love it

Comment: It's actually really great, but you should learn it well enough to write it yourself rather than going through an automatic JavaScript -> CoffeeScript converter, which is going to output pretty questionable code.

Comment: Try using sourcemaps to debug coffeescript!

Comment: @nemo "Not sure why rails love it" -- because it's super similar to Ruby